# Is it possible from a newly loaded page to insert an element onto a previously opened window document?

Tags: javascript

I have the following scenario,

action in window Window A triggers new window to open, window B.

Window B redirects user to third party service provider.
User authorizes access to information stored with service provider.
Service provider redirects user to list of documents within service provider environment
User selects a document, and service provider redirects user to hosting environment where window A code lies, but this is still happening in window B.
An image and a button "copy image to document" appear in window B.

Is it possible to copy/clone the img element onto Window A when the user clicks the button "copy image to document" in window B (I have complete control over code in window B)?
If so, what javascript method would I use to insert elements from window B onto window A?

Comment: That sounds rather spooky, allowing one site to manipulate the content of another site, even if the windows they're in have a parent/child relationship... I've got a sneaky suspicion it won't be permitted for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably window.opener will help you.

Comment: THANK YOU, when I wrote " redirects user to hosting environment where window A code lies" I meant same domain. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

This would only work if the both Window A and Window B are being served from the same domain at the time you are trying to read the data from window B.

If they are on the same domain, you can use window.opener to reference Window B from Window A. If not, the same-origin policy will prevent you from making that call.